# Find STDV of all nearest neighbor within cartesian coordinate

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
       X     Y       Z    Value
0      26.17 -7.68  109.22  27647.0
1      26.11 -7.64  109.24  27893.0
2      26.11 -7.63  109.24  27631.0
3      26.13 -7.66  109.23  27868.0
4      26.15 -7.67  109.23  27819.0
 ...   ...     ...      ...
83007  27.95 -4.50  109.75  28622.0
83008  27.97 -4.51  109.74  28499.0
83009  27.95 -4.49  109.75  29285.0
83010  27.96 -4.49  109.74  29728.0
83011  27.95 -4.47  109.74  29015.0

[83012 rows x 4 columns]
```

I have a dataframe with XYZ coordinate and value as above.

I want to find the standard deviation of the [Value] of all neighbor elements within 0.5 meters for each row.

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data is already loaded via `pandas`, this should give you the desired result (I used only first 5 rows of your data):

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

df['id'] = df.index.values
df['key'] = 1
joined = pd.merge(df, df, on='key')
joined['dist'] = joined.apply(lambda x: distance.euclidean([x['X_x'], x['Y_x'], x['Z_x']],
                                                           [x['X_y'], x['Y_y'], x['Z_y']]), axis=1)

joined = joined.loc[:, ~joined.columns.str.endswith('_y')]
joined = joined.rename(columns=lambda x: x.rstrip('_x'))
result = joined[joined['dist']<.5].groupby('id')['dist'].std()
df['std'] = result

df

       X     Y       Z    Value  id  key       std
0  26.17 -7.68  109.22  27647.0   0    1  0.033930
1  26.11 -7.64  109.24  27893.0   1    1  0.030416
2  26.11 -7.63  109.24  27631.0   2    1  0.033238
3  26.13 -7.66  109.23  27868.0   3    1  0.017481
4  26.15 -7.67  109.23  27819.0   4    1  0.023329
```